# Choosing an image based on option sent to class

Tags: header-footer, class-options

To be more consistent in the personal/internal documents I write, I'd like to modify my class to allow me to pass an option that will automatically select an image to put in the footer on the first page so what group I did the work for is readily seen at a glance. I'm not sure how to do it from here.

I have tried this:

```
    \DeclareOption{groupA}{\def\@affiliation{Group A}}
    \ProcessOptions \relax
```

In the footer definition, I added:

```
    \@ifundefined{\@affiliation}{\def\@affiliation{none}}{}
    \ifthenelse{\equal{\@affiliation}{\string groupA}}
        {\includegraphics[height=2cm]{groupA_logo.png}}
        {\@affiliation}
```

This was just to start trying it out, so it would include an image if I passed the `groupA` option through `\documentclass[groupA]{myreports}`, and just type out the affiliation if I use `groupB` or pass nothing.

This doesn't work out, though--my footer only gets the word none printed. Any ideas on how I could get something like this to work?

As requested, here's an MWE.
myreports.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myreports}[2015/07/28]
% - Declaration of options
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{geometry}}
\DeclareOption{groupA}{\def\@affiliation{Group A}}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
% ----- Execution of options
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper}
\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass{article}
% - Page Layout
\RequirePackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
% - Header and Footer Definitions
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \setlength\headheight{48pt}
    \setlength\headsep{-7pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\begin{center}
        First Page Header
    \end{center}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
        \@ifundefined{\@affiliation}{\def\@affiliation{none}}{}
        \ifthenelse{\equal{\@affiliation}{Group A}}
            {I'm in \@affiliation}
            {Don't recognize \@affiliation}
   }
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{48pt}
\setlength\headsep{-7pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\begin{center}
    Subsequent Pages Header
\end{center}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
% - maketitle Definition
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    \par\textsc{\huge\@title}
    \par\vspace{7pt}{\large\@author}
    \vspace{21pt}
    \par
}
\makeatother
\endinput
```

And test.tex:

```
\documentclass[groupA]{myreports}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\title{A Titled Report}
\author{It's Me!}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1-14]
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I was able to come up with a solution, though it changes track from what I was trying before. I do like this idea better, though, as it directly allows having more than one affiliation on a document.

I solved it by using \newif\if@groupA and then just simple \if@groupA {} \fi statements. I'll attach the resulting class below.

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{myreports}[2015/07/28]
\newif\if@groupA
\@groupAfalse
% - Declaration of options
\DeclareOption{letterpaper}{\PassOptionsToPackage{\CurrentOption}{geometry}}
\DeclareOption{groupA}{\@groupAtrue}
\DeclareOption*{\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}}
% ----- Execution of options
\ExecuteOptions{letterpaper}
\ProcessOptions \relax
\LoadClass{article}
% - Page Layout
\RequirePackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage{fancyhdr}
\RequirePackage{ifthen}
% - Header and Footer Definitions
\fancypagestyle{firstpage}{
    \fancyhf{}
    \setlength\headheight{48pt}
    \setlength\headsep{-7pt}
    \fancyhead[C]{\begin{center}
        First Page Header
    \end{center}}
    \fancyfoot[C]{
        \if@groupA
            I'm in group A
        \else
            I'm not in group A
        \fi
   }
}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{48pt}
\setlength\headsep{-7pt}
\fancyhead[CE,CO]{\begin{center}
    Subsequent Pages Header
\end{center}}
\fancyfoot[CE,CO]{\thepage}
% - maketitle Definition
\makeatletter
\def\maketitle{
    \thispagestyle{firstpage}
    \par\textsc{\huge\@title}
    \par\vspace{7pt}{\large\@author}
    \vspace{21pt}
    \par
} 
\makeatother
\endinput
```

Comment: You have plenty of spurious spaces.